# Extra padding under menu with child

Tags: css, menu, parent-child, padding, submenu

hey guys I am having a few issues with my menu, theres a weird padding that pushes my menu to the right a few pixels but I managed to fix it on the main parents, originally they were both pushing out the same amount.

Pic
[image]
and heres a better view
[image]

I am running through my css and adding **padding-left:0px;**

Heres my code if anyone can assist me.

```
<div class="css_menu_two_line">
<ul class="two_line_menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li><li>
    <a href="#">Menu 2</a></li><li class="current"><a href="#">Menu 3 SHOW</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3-3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3-4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3-5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li><li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li><li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.css_menu_two_line {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.two_line_menu {
padding-left: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    background:#77f url('img_bg.gif') repeat-x;
}

.two_line_menu a {
    display: block;
        color: #fff;

    text-decoration: none;
    padding:10px;
}

.two_line_menu li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #aaf;
}

.current a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #aaf;
}

.two_line_menu li { display: inline-block; }

.two_line_menu li ul {     display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #aaf;
    top: 38px; }

.two_line_menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #aaf;
    top: 38px;
}

.two_line_menu li ul li:hover a { color: #000; }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uf2cnakc/

Comment: Some code would help. Although the "weird padding" is probably coming from the default styles from `<ul>`.

Comment: Please post your html/css code and a fiddle to demonstrate the problem. Pics don't help..

Comment: What's your question?  Also, we are going to need to see some HTML and CSS.

Comment: I accidentally submitted (clicked enter) the post without posting the code and it jumped to show it.

Comment: You answered your own question while writing it.... You said there is extra padding, so why not try and set the padding to 0 on the elements you think is causing it. A lot of HTML elements have there own styles by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take away the padding from `.two_line_menu li ul`. To do this we can add the following style `padding: 0;`.

A lot of HTML elements have default styles, so beware of this.

Your CSS for this class should now look something like this:

```
.two_line_menu li ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #aaf;
    top: 38px;
    padding: 0; /* Just added */
}
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9wf3gLua/)

Comment: perfect that fixed it, also currently I have as a hover for one of the buttons a clas called **.current**. is there any way of simplifying that and making the menu show? pretty much I want it to automatically show that menu when on a certain page that has the current class on it.

Comment: .two_line_menu li:nth-child(3):hover this can replace .current:hover, also you will need to use jQuery to detect the current page.

Comment: @Grasper I have edited your answer to make it look better and with more info, please feel free to roll it back if you do not like the changes.

Comment: Im a little confused on how to replace and add that to my code. isnt it the 2nd not the 3rd dropdown menu? @Grasper

Comment: @BrianCherdak, well if it's 2nd use that. You need to learn it from trail and error.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS contained display:inline which has block child element and position absolute as well. Try this CSS property.

.two_line_menu li { display: block; float:left; }

.two_line_menu li ul{ position:absolute; left:0; padding:0; width:100%; background: #aaf; top:38px; }

.two_line_menu li ul li{ float:left;}